# Grub Solaris FreeBSD dual boot

Tags: grub, multi-boot, freebsd, solaris

I have solaris 10 installed on the first hard disk and freebsd installed on the second hard disk

I edited the /boot/grub/menu.lst from solaris to the following

```
title FreeBSD
root (hd1,0)
kernel /boot/loader
```

Now when I try to boot into freebsd via the grub, it gives the following error

```
root (hd1,0)
Filesystem type unknown, partition type 0xee
kernel /boot/loader
Error 17: cannot mount selected partition
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fix:**

Modify the /rpool/boot/grub/grub.cfg file and add the following just under the Solaris 11 menuentry

> menuentry "FreeBSD" {
>
> set root=(hd1,gpt2)
>
> kfreebsd /boot/loader
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

Possible failure reasons and fixes:

**You might be pointing at the wrong partition.** Try opening the GRUB prompt, (press c in the boot menu) enter `root (hd1,` and press tab. See if there are any other partitions available.

**The version of GRUB you're using may not support GPT.** Partition type `ee` typically means a fake MBR partition table indicator, indicating a GPT partition table. Update to a newer version of GRUB or try one of the workarounds below which might incidentally work.

**The file system you're using might not be supported by GRUB, or the version of GRUB you're using.** In this case, copying the `/boot/loader` file onto your Solaris partition and loading it from there might be a solution:

```
title FreeBSD
rootnoverify (hd1,0)
# The Solaris partition and directory where you have copied loader
kernel (hd0,0)/boot/loader
```

**You might have luck chainloading the MBR of the second disk.** Try something along the lines of:

```
title FreeBSD
rootnoverify (hd1,0)
chainloader (hd1)+1
```

or

```
title FreeBSD
rootnoverify (hd1,0)
chainloader (hd1,0)+1
```

Note that you can try the last two suggestions in the GRUB console, again invoked by pressing c at the boot menu, to avoid having to edit menu.lst and reboot multiple times. You might want to know that tab completion works and pressing tab twice bring up a list of suggestions. When trying thee commands at the GRUB prompt, leave out the `title` line, and end with the `boot` command to attempt to boot.

Comment: updating the grub version was the only way out. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try the chainloader statements? What was the result?

Comment: none of the above worked, had to update to Solaris 11 to get the new version of grub.